# in c++, multiset lower_bound or upper_bound sorts the set. what is the time complexity?

Tags: c++

from this example and descripton,
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/lower_bound/

```
// multiset::lower_bound/upper_bound
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main ()
{
  std::multiset<int> mymultiset;
  std::multiset<int>::iterator itlow,itup;

  for (int i=1; i<8; i++) mymultiset.insert(i*10); // 10 20 30 40 50 60 70

  itlow = mymultiset.lower_bound (30);             //       ^
  itup = mymultiset.upper_bound (40);              //             ^

  mymultiset.erase(itlow,itup);                    // 10 20 50 60 70

  std::cout << "mymultiset contains:";
  for (std::multiset<int>::iterator it=mymultiset.begin(); it!=mymultiset.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

I think in c++, multiset lower_bound or upper_bound  sorts the set. But what is the time complexity for this kind of operation?
is it o(nlogn) such as quick sort? or do anyone know what does this operation really do inside?

Comment: `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` don't sort the sequence, it's already sorted as elements are inserted.

Comment: The page that you linked to says the complexity for that function is `Logarithmic in size.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think in c++, multiset lower_bound or upper_bound sorts the set.

No.  A `std::multiset` is **always** sorted.

All of the `std::multiset` member functions **presume** that the contents are already sorted.

> But what is the time complexity for this kind of operation? is it o(nlogn) such as quick sort?

According to [your own link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/lower_bound/),

> ### Complexity
>
> Logarithmic in size.

That's O(log n).